# Spring Cloud Zuul + Undertow + OAuth2: Cannot log in to Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

We are using Spring Boot v2.0.4 + Spring Cloud (Finchley release).

We have deployed Zuul, Auth Server, Eureka, and Config Server, each in their own separate applications / processes. We have half a dozen of our own services deployed. We are using OAuth2 authentication for all services. We are using the embedded undertow container for all apps.

When Zuul uses the embedded Undertow container, we can not log in- the login page is redisplayed even though the credentials are correct. When Zuul is switched to use the embedded Tomcat container, everything works correctly- logging in brings the user to the correct page. (All other apps use Undertow in both cases.)

When we debug the requests coming through Zuul for Tomcat vs Undertow, we see that the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute is being set for Tomcat but is not being set for Undertow. I assume this means that the user will be redirected back to the login page, which is why we are seeing that behavior.

We know that it is an issue with Zuul + Tomcat vs. Undertow, since the configuration of all other apps remains exactly the same.

Any ideas? We are really scratching our heads over this one.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was caused by JSESSIONID cookie name conflict between Zuul and Auth Server. Because Tomcat container has different handling than Wildfly for multiple Set-Cookies of the same name (which is in violation of RFC6265), we are only seeing it now.

I should have mentioned that we configured auth server to be behind the Zuul proxy, hence the multiple JSESSIONID cookies.

We fixed this for now by renaming the JSESSIONID cookie name on all back-end servers. We will investigate the best way to do this for production deployment going forward, perhaps by using Spring Session. Any suggestions welcome.